# How can I hide notifications for a short period?

Tags: macos, notifications

I use notifications heavily as a sort of todo list during the day (mostly [Slack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_(software)) and email messages). But sometimes I want to hide these for a while to focus on the whole screen. If I disable notifications I often forgot for hours and find I missed something important. How can I hide the notifications for just 15 minutes and then have it reactivate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Mac app called [DND Me](https://runtimesharks.com/projects/dnd-me) which will allow you to turn on DND for a specific amount of time

There is a free trial on the website, otherwise the price is currently listed as €4.99.

*(I have used this app in the past and it worked as advertised. I am not otherwise affiliated with it in any way.)*

Comment: Thanks. Looks perfect for me. Will try it out

Answer (score 3):

One can use "Turn on Do Not Disturb" setting for needed time (From: to:), but this will come and bite you on following days if you forget to untick it.

I am not heavy notifications user but I simply ⌥ + click on Notifications Center icon to turn on / off notifications. Icon is dimmed when it's off and this visual clue is good enough for me (and I usually start worry when I have nothing to do for hours ;-)). Alternatively one can set own keyboard shortcut in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Mission Control -> Turn Do Not Disturb On/Off